# clear the "Usage " window

Tags: spyder

In the Spyder ide, how do I clear the "Usage" window from the help panel?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear'? If you mean showing the help plugin as an empty pane I think that is not possible. However, if what you want is to hide the Help pane, you can go to `View > Panes` and uncheck `Help`

Comment: I mean to get rid of that Usage window inside the help panel. I definitely want the help panel to remain so I can get help on any item during editing. Are you saying that is impossible? But I am supposed to be able to ctrl-I on anything in the editor and get help in that window, but nothing happens when I try it.

Comment: After the first time you use the `Ctrl+I` shortcut or the `inspect current object` action from the Editor or Console the `Usage page` should change to the information page available for the object you choosed to inspect. Sometimes there is no further info for an object and then a `No further documentation available` message should appear. I think you opened an issue at the Spyder Github repo and there a more complete answer about the Help pane functionality was given: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18953#issuecomment-1208273081

Comment: Thanks. I get it now

Comment: Glad to know you got the grip of how things are working :)